# flutter text widget overflow and multiline

Tags: flutter, text, overflow, multiline, longtext

some times when I'm coding with flutter, in the Text widget when I use long text, some times I get overflow message, and some times the message work right and be in many lines, why that's happen with me? please explain to me how to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some key property in Text Widgt:

```
  softWrap // if overflow then can wrap new line
  overflow // if overflow the overed text style
  maxLines // max lines
```

and if the parent container of Text Widgt has a width less or eq than device width then text overflowed will wrap to multiple lines, or Text will throw overflow error if text is too long

give a width to parent container

for example:

```
 // overflow error
 Container(
 child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
          "llohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
         "llohellohellohellohellohellohello"),
       Text("dd")
     ],
   ),
)
```

give parent container fix width

```
// overflow will change to multiple lines, notice padding and margin's effect

 Container(
 width: 100,
 child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
          "llohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
         "llohellohellohellohellohellohello"),
       Text("dd")
     ],
   ),
)
```

or let Text fill parant container using Expended or Flexible

```
Expanded(
 child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
          "llohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
         "llohellohellohellohellohellohello"),
       Text("dd")
     ],
   ),
)



// or 

Flexible(
 child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
          "llohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe" +
         "llohellohellohellohellohellohello"),
       Text("dd")
     ],
   ),
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your contribution. This seems like useful advise. Would you edit your answer to tidy up the indentation? As is, it's a bit difficult to read.